# How to generate new field dynamically in when I select check box in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

I wanted to get new field when i select check box like this.

```
**check box selected**
field1     field2 
**check box option** recursively
```

Comment: Can you add a some more information to the question?

Comment: Your question is very vague, I'm going to assume you are trying to show/hide fields based on the values of some boolean fields. This is done through the view's xml arch, by setting this attribute to the field tag you are trying to hide/unhide: `attrs="{'invisible': [('yout_checkbox_field', '!=', True)]}"`

Comment: i mean to say i may get many attributes dynamically . first we should get one check box1 if i select it i should get 2 fields with one checkbox2 . if i select checkbox2 then again i should get 2 fields with one more check box3

Answer (score 2):

You have teo options :

> **Option - 1**

Your view code can look like this :

```
<field name="bool_field1"/>
<field name="field1" attrs="{'invisible': [('bool_field','=',False)]}"/>
<field name="field2" attrs="{'invisible': [('bool_field','=',False)]}"/>
<field name="bool_field2"/>
```

So on, attrs will control your field visibility based on domain coded.

> **Option - 2**

This requirement lead to one2many relational database requirement, So If you want dymenic **N** Numbers of check-box then add `one2mnay field with three columns :

- bool_field1
- bool_field1
- bool_field2

So every time time when you **Add an Item** on one2mnay you will get N number of fields. In Odoo framework doing N field Dynamic field is not possible with just attrs as option1 above. You need relational talbe then do it.

Bests

Comment: ya i got it i want dyanmically .i mean i have to get unlimited fields . if i select one check box1 that should generate 2 fields and 1 more checkbox . for generated check box 2 if i selct this i should get one more like loop or recursive

Comment: @ShridharIvani : Updated my answer with more option you can use, You need o2m field .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31911789/at-tree-class-i-am-not-able-to-fielter-in-odoo please check this @firebug